# Unable to enter BIOS Recovery on HP Notebook but the OS boots normally

Tags: windows-10, boot, laptop, bios

I have noticed that after my BIOS update (F.29) I am getting abnormal CPU usage (around 20%) by a system process (ACPI.sys) and I have read in several forums that the BIOS update might be the reason.

So, I decided to downgrade my BIOS version to F.28 by flashing it on my USB stick. Now, when I try to enter the BIOS recovery screen by pressing Win + B then, **my laptop turns on but the screen is blank and caps lock key is blinking continuously**

I have tried flashing it on multiple USB sticks but same thing happens every time.

So, Can any one tell me what might be the problem and how to solve it?

Model - HP Notebook 15-ac673tx

**Note:** My PC boots completely fine (currently running Windows 10 Home) and can even enter the BIOS, its just the **BIOS Recovery** that I am unable to perform because of the aforementioned issue

Comment: "With the computer off, press and hold the Windows key and the B key at the same time.. Still pressing those keys, press and hold the Power button on the computer for 2 to 3 seconds, and then release the Power button But Continue to hold the Windows and B keys until the BIOS update screen displays or you hear a beeping sound (usually 8 beeps)."

Comment: I did exactly what you've mentioned but I can't hear any beeps or  see any bios update screen, in my case the the fan starts and the caps lock blinks.